# Confused about how my top tag and how the score is determined

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

Here's [My tags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4830093/daniel-turcich?tab=tags) and it says my top tag is Python however I received much less upvotes from Python than that of Angular which i have multiple over 1 and one with 9 yet it shows that i have a -1 score for Angular? How does this work I can't seem to find anything on this related to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tags page tracks *answer* score, not question score.

The tooltip for your Angular contributions belies this:

> **Asked** 19 non-wiki questions with a total score of 21. **Gave** 8 non-wiki answers with a total score of -1.

This is why your Angular tag has a score of -1; the sum total of points you've received on your Angular answers totals 1.

This is *also* why Python is the highest totaling tag for you; you've given answers in which the sum total score is 2.

> **Asked** 5 non-wiki questions with a total score of 2. **Gave** 2 non-wiki answers with a total score of 2.

Tag answer score matters in the context of [tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze).  You can earn tag badges with higher tag score, and a gold badge in a tag will allow you to unilaterally close any question tagged with that (that you didn't edit in beforehand) as a duplicate of another question, and allow you to unilaterally reverse that decision too.